# How to split up a bibtex reference type into different sections on a CV using to ModernCV

Tags: biblatex, moderncv, cv

I am trying to split up articles in my bibliography into two different sections on a CV. For example, the following MWE has 3 bibtex keys where two citations should appear in the first section and one citation in the second section.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}       

\addbibresource{Downey.bib}

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle

    \section{Education}
    \cventry{start-end}{<Position Held>}{<Name of employer>}{<Place>}{<Country>}{<Description>} % arguments 3 to 6 are optional

    \nocite{bib_key_1,bib_key_2}
    \printbibliography[title={Peer-Reviewed Journal articles}]

    \nocite{bib_key_3}
    \printbibliography[title={Peer-Reviewed Journal articles in press}]

\end{document}
```

With the bib file `Downey.bib`

```
% Encoding: ISO-8859-1

@Article{bib_key_1,
  author    = {\textbf{Author 1} and Author 2 and Author 3 and Author 4 and Author 5},
  title     = {Research paper},
  journal   = {Journal of science},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {065008},
  month     = {may},
  doi       = {10.1088/1361-665x/aa6b66},
  publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66},
}

@Article{bib_key_2,
  author    = {\textbf{Author 1} and Author 2 and Author 3 and Author 4 and Author 5},
  title     = {Research paper},
  journal   = {Journal of science},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {065008},
  month     = {may},
  doi       = {10.1088/1361-665x/aa6b66},
  publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66},
}

@Article{bib_key_3,
  author    = {\textbf{Author 1} and Author 2 and Author 3 and Author 4 and Author 5},
  title     = {Research paper},
  journal   = {Journal of science},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {065008},
  month     = {may},
  doi       = {10.1088/1361-665x/aa6b66},
  publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66},
}

@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

This results in a CV that looks like:
[image]

Notice that each bib entry appears in every section. How can I separate these sections such that entries only appear in one section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `biblatex` you can use the option `keyword=...` for command `\printbibliography` to divide the two parts.

You need to add the entry `keywords` to the bib entrys.

Please see the following MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{bib_key_1,
  author    = {\textbf{Author 1} and Author 2 and Author 3 and Author 4 and Author 5},
  title     = {Research paper},
  journal   = {Journal of science},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {065008},
  month     = {may},
  doi       = {10.1088/1361-665x/aa6b66},
  publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66},
  keywords  = {press},
}
@Article{bib_key_2,
  author    = {\textbf{Author 1} and Author 2 and Author 3 and Author 4 and Author 5},
  title     = {Research paper},
  journal   = {Journal of science},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {065008},
  month     = {may},
  doi       = {10.1088/1361-665x/aa6b66},
  publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66},
  keywords  = {no_press},
}
@Article{bib_key_3,
  author    = {\textbf{Author 1} and Author 2 and Author 3 and Author 4 and Author 5},
  title     = {Research paper},
  journal   = {Journal of science},
  year      = {2017},
  volume    = {26},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {065008},
  month     = {may},
  doi       = {10.1088/1361-665x/aa6b66},
  publisher = {{IOP} Publishing},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1088%2F1361-665x%2Faa6b66},
  keywords  = {press},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\moderncvstyle{classic}  
\moderncvcolor{blue}       

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle

    \section{Education}
    \cventry{start-end}{<Position Held>}{<Name of employer>}{<Place>}{<Country>}{<Description>} % arguments 3 to 6 are optional

    \nocite{bib_key_1,bib_key_2}
    \printbibliography[keyword={no_press},title={Peer-Reviewed Journal articles}]

    \nocite{bib_key_3}
    \printbibliography[keyword={press},title={Peer-Reviewed Journal articles in press}]

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a `\bibentry{}` approach in an
`enumerate` list that works well. I just have to compile the document a few times to make the .aux, then a bibtex compile to make the .bbl, and lastly another compile to see the PDF. Using the following main script,

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%            READ THIS TO GET IT TO COMPILE CORRECTLY                %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%                                                                    %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%                                                                    %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%% To get it to compile it is a 3 step process                        %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%% 1) Build and compile (F5 in TexStudio) to generate the .aux file   %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%% 2) Run bibtex (F8 or Tools>Commands>BibTeX in TexStudio)           %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%% 1) Build and compile (F5 in TexStudio) to generate the PDF         %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%                                                                    %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[letterpaper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% adding packages for bibtex publications  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem\@bibitem\makeatother
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}     % commented out as is already in modern CV
\makeatletter\let\@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}                                            % added to get rid of the "\lonely item" error. everthing in this list works [square,sort,comma,numbers]
\usepackage{enumitem}           % added for adjusting the indent of publications. adjusted locally at each list

% define the personal data used in the CV
\firstname{Joe}
\familyname{Smith}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{University}{City in a State} 
\email{email@University.edu} 
\homepage{www.Research.University.edu}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \nobibliography{publications}
    \bibliographystyle{plainurl}
    
    \section{Professional Academic Experience}
        \cvitem{2018 - present}{\textbf{Assistant Professor}, Department of Mechanical Engineering, University of a City in a State.}
        
    \section*{Publication Sub-list 1}
    
        \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1ex, leftmargin=2.5cm,labelsep=0.3cm]
            \item \bibentry{Hong2019TransverseVibrationClamped}
            \item \bibentry{Yan2019CapacitancebasedSensor}
        \end{enumerate}
    
    \section*{Publication Sub-list 2}
    
        \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=1ex, leftmargin=2.5cm,labelsep=0.3cm]
            \item \bibentry{Downey2020MillisecondModelUpdating}
            \item \bibentry{Downey2019Durabilityweatherabilitystyrene}
        \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

And this for bibref in a file called publications.bib

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
###############################################
# References (.bib) file for publications
###############################################

@Article{Yan2019CapacitancebasedSensor,
  author  = {Jin Yan and Austin Downey and An Chen and Simon Laflamme and Sammy Hassan},
  title   = {Capacitance-based Sensor With Layered Carbon-fiber Reinforced Polymer and Titania-filled Epoxy},
  journal = {Composite Structures},
  year    = {2019},
  volume  = {227},
  pages   = {111247},
  issn    = {0263-8223},
  doi     = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.compstruct.2019.111247},
  url     = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263822319312905},
}


@Article{Downey2020MillisecondModelUpdating,
  author    = {Austin Downey and Jonathan Hong and Jacob Dodson and Michael Carroll and James Scheppegrell},
  journal   = {Mechanical Systems and Signal Processing},
  title     = {Millisecond model updating for structures experiencing unmodeled high-rate dynamic events},
  year      = {2020},
  month     = {April},
  pages     = {106551},
  volume    = {138},
  doi       = {10.1016/j.ymssp.2019.106551},
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
}

@Article{Hong2019TransverseVibrationClamped,
  author    = {Jonathan Hong and Jacob Dodson and Simon Laflamme and Austin Downey},
  journal   = {Applied Sciences},
  title     = {Transverse Vibration of Clamped-Pinned-Free Beam with Mass at Free End},
  year      = {2019},
  month     = jul,
  number    = {15},
  pages     = {2996},
  volume    = {9},
  doi       = {10.3390/app9152996},
  publisher = {{MDPI} {AG}},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.3390/app9152996},
}

@Article{Yan2019CapacitancebasedSensor,
  author  = {Jin Yan and Austin Downey and An Chen and Simon Laflamme and Sammy Hassan},
  journal = {Composite Structures},
  title   = {Capacitance-based Sensor With Layered Carbon-fiber Reinforced Polymer and Titania-filled Epoxy},
  year    = {2019},
  issn    = {0263-8223},
  pages   = {111247},
  volume  = {227},
  doi     = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.compstruct.2019.111247},
  url     = {http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0263822319312905},
}

@Article{Downey2019Durabilityweatherabilitystyrene,
  author    = {Austin Downey and Anna Laura Pisello and Elena Fortunati and Claudia Fabiani and Francesca Luzi and Luigi Torre and Filippo Ubertini and Simon Laflamme},
  journal   = {Sensors and Actuators A: Physical},
  title     = {Durability and weatherability of a styrene-ethylene-butylene-styrene ({SEBS}) block copolymer-based sensing skin for civil infrastructure applications},
  year      = {2019},
  month     = jul,
  pages     = {269--280},
  volume    = {293},
  doi       = {10.1016/j.sna.2019.04.022},
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
  url       = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.sna.2019.04.022},
}


@Comment{jabref-meta: databaseType:bibtex;}
```

You will get this result with modernCV.
[image]